# rpm build from src file

Tags: fedora, rpm

I'm trying to build from a *.src.rpm file on FC 12 in such a way that the files are distributed a across my system as they would with a normal binary build (in this case, *.h files end up in /usr/include).  When I ran rpmbuild, the headers weren't present.  Here's my rpmbuild command:

```
[root@localhost sphirewalld]# rpm -ivv /home/dan/Downloads/gtest-1.3.0-2.20090601svn257.fc12.src.rpm
============== /home/dan/Downloads/gtest-1.3.0-2.20090601svn257.fc12.src.rpm
Expected size:       489395 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(489115)
  Actual size:       489395
loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
loading keyring from rpmdb
opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm/Packages cdb:mpool:joinenv
opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name rdonly mode=0x0
 read h#     931 Header sanity check: OK
added key gpg-pubkey-57bbccba-4a6f97af to keyring
 read h#    1327 Header sanity check: OK
added key gpg-pubkey-7fac5991-4615767f to keyring
 read h#    1420 Header sanity check: OK
added key gpg-pubkey-16ca1a56-4a100959 to keyring
 read h#    1896 Header sanity check: OK
added key gpg-pubkey-a3a882c1-4a1009ef to keyring
Using legacy gpg-pubkey(s) from rpmdb
/home/dan/Downloads/gtest-1.3.0-2.20090601svn257.fc12.src.rpm: Header SHA1 digest: OK (3e98ed9b1631395d417e00f35c83ebe588ea9d3b)
     added source package [0]
found 1 source and 0 binary packages
Expected size:       489395 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(489115)
  Actual size:       489395
InstallSourcePackage at: psm.c:232: Header SHA1 digest: OK (3e98ed9b1631395d417e00f35c83ebe588ea9d3b)
gtest-1.3.0-2.20090601svn257.fc12
========== Directories not explicitly included in package:
         0 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
         1 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/
==========
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
fini      100664  1 (   0,   0)    478034 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/gtest-1.3.0.tar.bz2;4ba93ce1 unknown
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
fini      100644  1 (   0,   0)     30505 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/gtest-svnr257.patch;4ba93ce1 unknown
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
fini      100644  1 (   0,   0)      2732 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/gtest.spec;4ba93ce1 unknown
GZDIO:      63 reads,   511788 total bytes in 0.005930 secs
closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm/Packages
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I don't use Fedora so I can't be sure, but I see this has gone unanswered for some time. I do build extensive numbers of RPM's, but for a different distro (PLD).

Your output doesn't say much about what DID get generated. Are you sure a -devel subpackage did not get generated along with the main binary rpm? Did you look at the files inside the src.rpm package and make sure the files you're looking for are in there? Are there any flags for your rpmbuild script to say "include devel files" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is quite likely no longer relevant, but `rpm -i(vv)` can not be used to build a binary RPM package from a source RPM package. This requires the use of `rpmbuild`, e.g. `rpmbuild --rebuild /<…>/gtest-1.3.0-2.20090601svn257.fc12.src.rpm`. All that is actually happening with `rpm -i(vv)` for a source RPM package is that the content of the source RPM package is extracted into the rpmbuild directory structure, specifically `/root/rpmbuild/{SOURCES,SPECS}/` in this case. To build this filled rpmbuild directory structure, `cd /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/` followed by `rpmbuild -ba gtest.spec` could be used (which I would not recommend, because RPM packages should not be built as privileged user, because a mistake or a bug in the software and/or the spec file could damage your operating system when accidentially referring to a path outside of the build environment).